# Is it possible to optimize garbage collection (GC) time cost by determining some good collection opportunities at compile time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, runtime, compiler-optimization, garbage

Usually the necessity of GC is evaluated at runtime.
But, is there any idea or implementation to determine good timing for GC opportunity at compile time? For example, we may be able to collect garbage safely with a concurrent thread without locking the whole runtime. We may be sure that some old objects do not need GC.

Comment: About the only time you really know that at compile time is when an object reference is on the stack and doesn't escape the method. In that case the object can be destroyed immediately on method exit, like a C++ object in automatic storage. But GC already runs in its own thread, and GC already knows what objects are reachable.

Comment: Concurrent collectors do already exist. But concurrent execution contradicts the idea of having a particular point of time in general, whether that non-existing point would be determined at runtime or at compile time. The question simply makes no sense.